# Vue router push same path different query or param, reload the different content of page

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a v-text-field search box. Press the enter key and the search box will call search(keyword)
in search(keyword):

```
this.$router.push({path:'/search', query:{keyword:keyword}});
```

In the first time I search a keyword like `vacuum` it works, the page can render the search result page,
then I search another keyword like `air`, it doesn't re-render the search result page for keyword `air`.
Now I use `this.$router.go(0)` to reload the page:

```
this.$router.push({path:'/search', query:{keyword:keyword}});
this.$router.go(0)
```

it can work. But my web api server will show `tcp-write: error writing  system error:An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.; errid=10053`.

So, I want to know what other methods can reload page when same path but different query or param.

Comment: Navigating to the current route won't affect a re-render, you need to bind a key to your `<router-view>` element and change its value on each search, refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57721877/10756332

Comment: I use .watch{} and solved the problem , thank you